# CakePHP with React Router

Tags: cakephp, react-router

Is it possible to use React Router with CakePHP? I have the following route setup.

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/editPage">
        <MyComponent />
   </Route>
</Switch>
```

When I navigate to `localhost\editPage` in my URL. Cake throws exception:
`Cake\Http\Exception\MissingControllerException`

I am unfamiliar with routes in CakePHP. Is there anyway to disable this for certain urls? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CakePHP as a backend application, then you need to consider how your frontend application communicates with it. In most cases your frontend app communicates via the RESTful API.

You need to prepare your CakePHP app for this task.

Here is how to:

- **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/rest.html**
- **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes**

**Routes**:

```
// https://example.com
$builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
// https://example.com/editPages
$builder->connect('/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
```

In PagesController create index method and use empty layout.

```
public function index()
{
   $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
}
```

In `templates/Pages` create `index.php` as your react layout.
Then in `webroot/` add rest of your react app.

from react fetch backend rest api, for example http://example.com/posts/edit/1.json

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are embedding your react app into Cake. You can create a Component that decodes the asset-manifest.json and sets the assets to the manifest contents, then create a specific Controller that embeds the component into a view.

See https://toggen.com.au/it-tips/embedding-a-create-react-app-project-into-a-cakephp-view/ for a great guide to this.

With that done, you just need a wildcard connect in your routes.php scope that sends traffic to that controller.

```
$builder->connect('/*', ['controller' => 'React', 'action' => 'embed']);
```

If you're hosting other views via other controllers you'll need to add a separate scope with the specific paths that aren't part of the react app.